# Using ouput of ParametericNDSolve as argument in NMinimize: NMinimize::nnum: function value not a number

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to fit some experimental data and I am trying to use [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html) function to calculate the parameters that fit the experimental dataset. I am also using [`ParametricNDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) and I can't make it to work together.

This is a toy example:

```
sol0 = ParametricNDSolve[{x'[t] == k*x[t], x[0] == x0}, {x[t]}, {t, 0, 100}, {k, x0}]
```

So I have to find `k` and `x0` that best fit the exp data

The data is:

```
data = RandomReal[{0.95 #,  1.05 #}] & /@ ((x[t][1, 10] /. sol0 /. t -> #) & /@ Range[0, 10])
```

> ```
> {9.59679, 27.9723, 73.9852, 190.905, 534.717, 1421.69, 4178.41, 11296.8, 30648.2, 79970.6, 229304.}
> ```

I create an objective function:

```
objfn[k_, x0_] := 
 Norm[((  x[t][k, x0] /. sol0 /. t -> #  ) & /@ 
     Table[i, {i, 0, 10}]) - data]
```

Now I try to find the paramters:

```
NMinimize[{objfn[k, x0], k > 0, x0 > 0}, {k, x0}]
```

I've got a relative long error message that starts with

> NMinimize::nnum.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out the changes that I have to introduce to make this work. I would really appreciate if any could help me.

Thank you very much in advance
Fernando

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimum** working examples of **code and data** in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help). As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Comment: There are [things to do after your question has been answered](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but don't rush, you may want stay vigilant some time after you get the first answer as its likely that the best approaches may come later improving over a previous reply. Therefore, its a good idea to **wait at least 24 hours** before [voting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the deserving answers and [accepting](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the best one for you. (Links contain useful information)

Comment: @rhermans I noticed that you have started using the welcome comment above, and I agree with your recommendations overall, especially with the one regarding waiting a while to accept an answer. I wonder, though: should one really wait as long as 24 hours before *voting up* deserving answers?

Comment: @MarcoB votes get locked after some time, and some issues with the answer may become evident only after discussion. Because of the time zone differences the comments that may reveal those issues may not come within a few hours. But I concede that this "restriction" is open for discussion and I do not have the final word.

Answer (score 2):

Notice the details of the error:

> NMinimize::nnum: The function value [...] is not a number at {k,x0} = {1.91862,1.66351}. >>

You need to be sure that `objfn` doesn't evaluate until is given a [`Real`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Real.html) value as argument. For that, change `objfn[k_, x0_]` to `objfn[k_Real, x0_Real]`.

You can also avoid the substitution [`Rule`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) and evaluate the functions directly.

```
objfn[k_Real, x0_Real] := 
 Norm[Table[sol0[[1, 2]][k, x0], {t, 0, 10}] - data]
```

Now this definition of `objfn` can be used with [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html)

```
NMinimize[{objfn[k, x0], k > 0, x0 > 0}, {k, x0}]
```

> ```
> {527.089, {k -> 0.990979, x0 -> 10.6917}}
> ```

Comment: Hi @rhermans, Many thanks for the prompt answer.

Comment: My pleasure! You can return the favor, As you receive help you can give back. Stay in the community, earn reputation and badges, learn and share what you have learned.